# How is a python decorator actually defined?

Tags: python, decorator

First of all I know what a decorator is. I would like to understand some small aspects.

**TL;DR**

```
is decorator func1 = func2(func1) # True
is decorator func3 = func2(func1) # ???
```

---

Let's look at [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators) which describes two equivalent ways to decorate a function:

```
@viking_chorus
def menu_item():
    print("spam")

def menu_item():
    print("spam")
menu_item = viking_chorus(menu_item)
```

Now, let's see the description on this [website](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/decorator), particularly in the section *Getting back to decorators*. There are two functions defined:

```
def make_pretty(func):
    def inner():
        print("I got decorated")
        func()
    return inner

def ordinary():
    print("I am ordinary")
```

And then an author decorates the function and calls it:

```
>>> pretty = make_pretty(ordinary)
>>> pretty()
I got decorated
I am ordinary
```

We can notice that the author doesn't use:

```
>>> ordinary = make_pretty(ordinary)
```

which is a recommended way by Wiki (I know that Wiki can be sometimes wrong). So I decided to use the last way to decorate the Fibonacci numbers function taken from this [tutorial](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php):

```
def memoize(f):
    memo = {}
    def helper(x):
        if x not in memo:            
            memo[x] = f(x)
        return memo[x]
    return helper


def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

This call:

```
>>> fib_element = memoize(fib)
>>> fib_element(40)
```

takes a long time on my machine which means that the `fib()` has been not decorated properly. The execution time is comparable with `fib(40)`. These calls:

```
>>> fib = memoize(fib)
>>> fib_element = fib # assigned after decoration
>>> fib(40)
>>> fib_element(40)
```

execute fast. So the question is: can we say that we decorate the `ordinary` function in `pretty = make_pretty(ordinary)` assignment?

Comment: Technically, there is no distinct object called a decorator; it's really just a function that takes a function as an argument and returns (or is expected to return) another function. What *is* special is decorator *syntax*, which provides a concise way to apply the decorator function. `@foo def bar(): ...` is shorter than `def bar(): ...; bar = foo(bar)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the first call to `fib_element(40)` is slow is that you don't decorate recursively: The `fib` function doesn't know about your memoization. If you call `fib_element` repeatedly on the same element, the first call will be slow, the other ones very fast.

Since `fib` calls `fib` (which refers to the decorated function in the second example, but the original function in the first example), you need to give it the same name to benefit from memoization with this decoration method.

Comment: So if the `fib` function doesn't know about memoization during the first call, why the second and next calls with the same argument (as you mentioned) use the dictionary and the `fib_element(N)` works fast? This suggests that `fib` knows about memoization.

Comment: Because `fib` is now the memoized `fib`.

Comment: Actually `fib_element = fib` only make the two names point to the very same function, they are not distinct functions.